# Getting the error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal at cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: asp.net

I am inserting and updating the records through the same button. But I want the primary key(req_no) to be auto generated during insert operation only and not on update. How to do it ? 
 Getting the error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal   at  cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
here is the code:

```
    public partial class Service_master : System.Web.UI.Page
       {

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Session["UserName"] = "laxmi";
        this.TextBox9.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        lb1.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
          if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDropDownList();
            BindDropDowns();
            Bindservcd();


        }
    }


       private void Autogenrate()
        {
           int r;

            try
            {
            con.Open();
            TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox1");
            string sqlcmd = "Select max(req_no)as req_no from service_master";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           if (dr.Read())
        {

            string d = dr[0].ToString();
            if (d == "")
            {
            TextBox1.Text = "1" ;
            }
                else
            {

                r = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                r = r + 1;
                TextBox1.Text = r.ToString();
            }
        }
                con.Close();

            }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                       WebMsgBox.Show("null is not allowed");
                            }

        }
 public bool uniquereq_no(string req_no)
{
        string strreqno;
        string querye = "select count(req_no) as req_no from service_master where req_no='"+ this.TextBox1.Text.ToString()+"'" ;
        OleDbCommand cmnd = new OleDbCommand(querye, con);
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        dr = cmnd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                strreqno = dr["req_no"].ToString();
                return (strreqno != "0");
                if (strreqno != "0")
                {
                    WebMsgBox.Show("already exists");
                    //errlblemail.Text = "email already exist";
                    return false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string message = "error";
                message += e.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
        }

        return true;


    }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string UserName = "UserName";
        Session["UserName"] = lb1.Text;

        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox TextBox9 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox9");
        TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox2");
        TextBox TextBox3 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox3");
        TextBox TextBox4 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox4");
        DropDownList DropDownList3 = (DropDownList)FindControl("DropDownList3");
        DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)FindControl("DropDownList1");
        TextBox TextBox5 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox5");
        TextBox TextBox6 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox6");
        DropDownList DropDownList2 = (DropDownList)FindControl("DropDownList2");
        TextBox TextBox7 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox7");
        TextBox TextBox8 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox8");


        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (uniquereq_no(TextBox1.Text)== true)
            {
                cmnd.CommandText = "upd_ser_mas";
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_no", OleDbType.Numeric, 8).Value = 
                  Convert.ToString(this.TextBox1.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_dt", OleDbType.Date).Value = 
           Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox9.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_by", OleDbType.VarChar, 7).Value = Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xser_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox3.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xserv_desc", OleDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox4.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xserv_grp_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xbase_uom_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xsac_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox5.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xser_long_desc", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox6.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xtax_ind", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xactive_ind", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox7.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xdel_ind", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox8.Text);
                WebMsgBox.Show("Data Successfully Updated");
            }
            else
            {
                Autogenrate();
                cmnd.CommandText = "ins_ser_mas";
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_no", OleDbType.Numeric, 8).Value = Convert.ToString(this.TextBox1.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_dt", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox9.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_by", OleDbType.VarChar, 7).Value = Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xser_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox3.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xserv_desc", OleDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox4.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xserv_grp_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xbase_uom_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xsac_cd", OleDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox5.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xser_long_desc", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox6.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xtax_ind", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xactive_ind", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox7.Text);
                cmnd.Parameters.Add("xdel_ind", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox8.Text);
                WebMsgBox.Show("The data for request number" + TextBox1.Text + "is saved");
            }
            cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Use `decimal.Parse` to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Thanks for posting code, but it contains a lot of stuff that is totally irrelevant to your question. You need to keep it minimal so we can provide better and faster answers. Please see **[ask]**.

Comment: Please correct formatting of your code

Answer (score 1):

`OleDbType.Numeric` has equivalent data type of `System.Decimal` as given in [`OleDbType` enumeration reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320435/info-oledbtype-enumeration-vs-microsoft-access-data-types). You need to use decimal conversion with `decimal.Parse` or `Convert.ToDecimal` for this line since `TextBox1.Text` returns string value:

```
cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_no", OleDbType.Numeric, 8).Value = decimal.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text);
```

Or you can use safer `decimal.TryParse` method:

```
decimal xreqNo;

bool isDecimalValue = decimal.TryParse(this.TextBox1.Text, out xreqNo);
if (isDecimalValue)
{
    cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_no", OleDbType.Numeric, 8).Value = xreqNo; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things in your code could be corrected

1) No need to use `ExecuteReader`. Use `ExecuteScalar` instead. Since its just one value being returned. (In `SQL` mentioned after point 2 below)

2) Changed `sql` query to do the +1 part of code. (*If your db supports ISNull)*. Otherwise there could be something similar in your db.

```
//SQL query will find max and will do +1
var sqlcmd = "Select IsNull(max(req_no),0) + 1 as req_no from service_master";
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, con);
var outval  = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       //now outval will have value
TextBox1.Text = outval.ToString();
```

3) You are assigning `string` values to parameters but the types assigned are different.

```
cmnd.Parameters.Add("xreq_no", OleDbType.Numeric, 8).Value = Convert.ToString(this.TextBox1.Text);
```

TextBox1.Text is itself `string`, you dont have to use `Convert.ToString`. OR use correct conversion like `Convert.ToInt32`, etc since your parameter is `OledbType.Numeric`, etc

Also, Why you have to use `FindControl`? Remove `FindControl`

```
TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)FindControl("TextBox1");
```

`TextBox1` can be referred directly.